# file upload using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can we upload a jpeg on UI via automation?

At present I have the image placed in my repo under resources and I'm doing the following code

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("mypicId"));
File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.jpg").toURI());
element.sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

element I'm sending a file to is an

I'm expecting the file to be uploaded but I get the following error
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument: File not found : test.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("mypicId"));
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/java/resources/test.jpg"));
//or


// File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/test.jpg"));
element.sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: thank you, but I still get the same error. I tried with chrome 69 as well
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument: File not found : 
(Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 196 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28',

Comment: It says File not found. Please reply with where the file is related to Src folder.

Comment: Ok, when I do sendKeys, its calling this.fileDetector.getLocalFile(keysToSend) and this calls the below class. It always returns null?
public class UselessFileDetector implements FileDetector {
    public UselessFileDetector() {
    }

    public File getLocalFile(CharSequence... keys) {
        return null;
    }
}

Comment: Is this running locally or in a Grid? Is there any way you can use a different browser?

Comment: I tried with the same code what I have above, the only issue was that it was running in a grid and couldn't find the file, when I tried locally it worked.